# Different classes have to implement an interface method in exactly the same way

Tags: c#, interface

I have and interface defining a bunch of different properties and a *State* property that is a compact summary of all the other.

So I have a common interface named `IStateful`

```
interface IStateFul
{
    string State { get; set; }
}
```

I have some classes implementing this interface in different ways - one asks for user input, another read the values from a service, one could get data from a DB.
But all of them have to compute the state in exactly the same way to be "compatible" with each other. So the implementation of `State` in the different classes have to use the other property in exactly the same way to compute the state string.

As of today I copy and paste the state implementing method from a class to the other. This is obviously the worst option.

Other options could be

- Common abstract base class (I tried this and it's ankward, the abstract class have to implement abstractly all the interface method that it does not care at all, then the derived classes have to override them all)
- Another class with a static method to be called (a "serializer" ???)
- An extension method for the interface (just the same as option 2 but with different sintactic sugar)

There is a common pattern to follow? Or is there a basic design flaw that I'm missing to see?

Answer (score 3):

In an abstract class you should only mark the methods that *need* to be overridden as `abstract`, otherwise mark them `virtual`:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    protected virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        //My Implementation here
        Console.WriteLine("Base implementation");
    }

    //Will give compile-time error if you don't override this in derived class
    protected abstract void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Then in your derived classes you can use either the base implementation of the virtual methods or override them and the abstract methods will need to be implemented:

```
public class Derived : MyBase
{
    protected override void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived implementation");
    }
}

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var derived = new Derived();
    derived.DoSomething();      //Base Implementation
    derived.DoSomethingElse();  //Derived implementation
}
```

Comment: Your example abstract class is not implementing an interface.

Comment: Implement them in the abstract class

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't see how this is related to what I'm asking

Comment: @edc65 You want a common implementation for some interfaces in the base class, you can do that with an abstract class. Obviously you'll have to override the ones they don't have in common in the derived classes? I don't think I really understand your issue

Answer (score 1):

If using an interface is not absolutely required by your design, you can use an abstract class *instead* of the interface and not both at the same time. It will work practically the same way but allows you to define a method/property implementation.

Your case is a common pattern addressed by abstract classes.

Comment: I can easily implement an interface in a class. I cannot disrupt my class hierarchy to add a base abstract class. I would need to use composition and add a member derived from the base abstract class instead ... as I said, it's ankward

Answer (score 0):

I would define the interface IRequireState

```
public interface IRequireState
{
    bool GetState();
}
```

And use that for all classes requiring state. There is a programming principle called "[The Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)" (ISP) which basically states that you should ONLY implement an interface in the classes where it makes sense to do so.

According to the [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) you can always subtitute a derivative, so for example, if you have 3 classes, all implementing the IRequireState you can then type code like:

```
foreach(var job in myListOfJobs)
  if(job.GetType() == typeof(IRequireState))
    ((IRequireState)job).GetState();
```

I hope that helps you on the path to good Object Oriented design. Make sure to read up on the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). They help alot in these questions.

If you have some jobs that do the same GetState() thing, then it would make sense to have a base class which implements the same interface, but you're then free to ALSO have jobs with various, different GetState() implementations.

Comment: I know that I'm free, but I need to be constrained instead. I addes some details in my question

Comment: Adding those constraints is a good practice. The SOLID principles more or less make you avoid code duplications, and follow a more rigid, disciplined code that is easy to read, maintain, and understand :)